# Запустить процесс win32 api без зависания вызывающего процесса

Tags: c, winapi

Здравствуйте, всем известна функция CreateProcess, запускаем примерно так

```
if(CreateProcess(...))
{
     WaitForSingleObject(...);
}
CloseHandle(...);
```

Нигде не нашел как запускать процесс, чтобы вызывающий процесс не зависал, помогите. Перепробовал кучу флагов внутри createprocess(), в том числе и менял environment variables - так и не получилось.

Comment: А вы пробовали WaitForSingleObject убирать?

Comment: честно говоря, нет

Comment: Имя функции говорящее... Чтение MSDN при возникновении проблем с WinAPI - первое, что нужно делать.

Comment: ну да, убрали waitforsingleobject и больше не висит вызывающий процесс...
теперь другой вопрос - как теперь убить через определенное время процесс этот? создать поток отдельный, в нем подождать это время и из него сделать terminateprocess?

Comment: А вы попробуйте

Answer (score 3):

"Зависает", а точнее ждет, не CreateProcess, а WaitForSingleObject. Специально уточнил: про ожидание CreateProcess в MSDN ничего нет.